# Ajax request is not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, http

I am trying to get data from db using ajax. When a date is selected from inline calender then that date will be captured and query  will be done and ive to show the holiday status of the selected date.
 but the ajax request is not working, how to know whether it is working or not.

my code is

```
$(function () {
    $("#divCalendar").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "mm-dd-yy",
        onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
            //alert("You clicked on " + selectedDate.toString());
            var dataString = 'sdt='+ selectedDate.toString();
            //alert("You clicked on " + dataString);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url:"demotest.php",
                data: dataString,
                dataType : "json",
                success:function(data){
                    if(data != "ERROR")  
                    {
                        $("#div1").html(data);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $("#div1").html("nothing found");    
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Does your php script work by itself? Perhaps, you should post it here too

Comment: Your tittle should be more clear. try...... You can

Comment: What do you mean bynot working.Is the request sending to `demotest.php`.Is there any errors.Have you checked the console.?

Comment: would you let me know how to see the errors in console

Comment: Try F12 after opening the browser(chrome or firefox) and you can see developer console.And you could see errors in red color and if you choose network you can see the log of http requests.

Comment: Please put an appropriate question title so that more people can get attention..!!

Comment: the console says     [15:51:45.133] The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol. @ http://localhost/calender_testing/inlinecalender.php

Comment: paste your server php code please

Answer (score 1):

in [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), `dataType` parameter refers to the type of data that you're expecting back from the server as ajax response. You are setting that in your call to json.

But the line

```
$("#div1").html(data);
```

seems like you are expecting a normal `text` or `html` response. If the response is not valid json the ajax call will not work. Else you remove the `dataType : "json",` line and let the ajax utility look for a default text response.

You can get hints regarding the error encountered in your ajax call by checking the browser console (chrome inspector/firebug).

Answer (score 0):

The `dataType:` attribute represents the type of data to be returned as response from server. But from you coding it seems like your response data is a simple string or text.so you can give like this `dataType:"text,"` or you could just ignore `datatType` attribute, since by default it is text.

Try this ,it is working

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url:"demotest.php",
                data: {
                       us:"hi"
                        },

               success:function(data){
                    if(data != "ERROR")  
                    {
                        $("#div1").html(data);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $("#div1").html("nothing found");    
                    }
                }
            });
```